# Raw PHP or PHP frameworks is Better?

Tags: php

I am new to php.
I have developed few small projects using php,ajax,java script,j query and MySQL.
My question is,Should i go for php frame works? 
or can i survive just working on RAW PHP. 
I feel Raw php gives me more flexibility.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Question is opinion-based, but personally speaking I've gotten by just fine writing my own code. If you do choose a framework, be sure to pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: IMO: If you know php well enough and OPP concept then its time to learn new tools (Frameworks), Frameworks provides you code that you can make yourself or know what the code does. Frameworks are just DRY, Toolkit & standard set of architecture of code to follow. So if you use hammer to nail and not a spoon you are good to go. Search pros & cons of framework and you'll have a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anyone will argue that frameworks add a big performance overhead - but the impact seems unrelated to the popularity of the framework.

The key questions you should be asking are:

**is the code more secure than something you write yourself**

Read the documentation, read the code. If there's part of code which look odd, have they been explained? Whats the change histories on those blocks? Are there published CVE numbers for the framework, if so, how long did it take for the holes to get fixed? Do you have the means to ensure the fixes are deployed to your infrastructure promptly?

Like performance, the Security of frameworks does not correlate with popularity.

**does using the framework save you time/money/effort**

You are going to have to do a lot of reading docs, writing/testing code before you have a good understanding of framework. The advantage in collaborative environments is that you're all working on the same reference point but at a higher level of abstraction than raw PHP. But it does require a lot of up-front effort. Indeed one of the reasons there are so many PHP frameworks is that they are just as difficult to learn as they are to write. (side note - the [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) attempts to disconnect the interface from the implementation). Sadly you can't answer this question without investing a lot of time in learning one or more frameworks.

**what do you want?**

If you're seeking a career in web development, then learn Java....whoops almost went off on a rant there....if you are looking to improve your employment prospects then....employers recognise the learning curve for frameworks and, since they will probably already be using some sort of framework, will be interested in candidate who is bringing more to the table.

Answer (score 0):

It might be fine for really small projects, but having the base components (e.g. request/response objects, router, controllers, templating system) already available and working would help. Then you can focus on the project itself instead of re-inventing something that has been done a million times already.